# t-sql to create tables using a declared variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to create multiple tables in multiple databases using declared variables for the db_name, table_name , column_name and column_type. Is this feasible ? I have to create the same tables for 14 databases. The tables are the same for the databases but there are multiple tables and multiple columns.

Sample:

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(250) = (SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id >= 337); --Newly Created Databases
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(250) = (SELECT TableName FROM DB.Table.Tables WHERE Enabled = 1);
DECLARE @TableId INT = (SELECT Id FROM DB.Table.Tables WHERE Enabled = 1);
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(250) = (SELECT ColumnName FROM DB.Table.Columns WHERE Enabled = 1 AND TableId = @TableId);
DECLARE @ColumnType VARCHAR(250) = (SELECT ColumnType FROM DB.Table.Columns WHERE Enabled = 1 AND TableId = @TableId);

USE [master];

CREATE TABLE [@DBName + '.dbo.' + @TableName] (@ColumnName + @ColumnType);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! You will probably have to create a script with one or more cursors and dynamic sql to script out the create statements. What do you mean with this part: `SELECT TableName FROM DB.Table.Tables WHERE Enabled = 1` Do you mean `DbName.sys.tables` ? What does the `WHERE Enabled = 1` stand for?

Comment: Hi, and thank you! The SELECT TableName FROM DB.Table.Tables WHERE Enabled = 1 is referring to a table(ref_table) that has specific tablenames in it , we use that for a replication process. I am trying to only create those tables listed in that table(ref_table) for the new databases. The WHERE Enabled = 1 stands for the table being actively replicated , this is so I only create the active tables.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Only using the hardcoded ref_table would be ok then?

Comment: The ref_table itself is acting in a way as a lookup table and I need to use the tables listed in the TableName column as my create table names. I am not sure if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to employ a little semi-advanced dynamic T-SQL for this task.

First, I'll create a small [MCVE](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/mcve?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=dba.stackexchange.com&utm_campaign=234344) in tempdb.  In future, please create this part yourself when asking questions here :-)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE tempdb;
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'Table') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [Table].Columns;
    DROP TABLE [Table].Tables;
    DROP SCHEMA [Table];
END
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [Table]
CREATE TABLE [Tables]
(
    TableID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT Tables_pk
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , TableName sysname NOT NULL
    , [Enabled] bit NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [Columns]
(
    ColumnID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT Columns_pk
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , TableID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT Columns_TableID
        FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES [Tables](TableID)
    , ColumnName sysname NOT NULL
    , ColumnType nvarchar(150) NOT NULL
    , Nullable bit NOT NULL
    , [Enabled] bit NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Here, I'm create a single row in `[Table].Tables`, with two columns `a`, and `b`.

```
INSERT INTO [Table].Tables (TableID, TableName, [Enabled])
VALUES (1, N'a', 1);

INSERT INTO [Table].Columns (ColumnID, TableID, ColumnName, ColumnType, Nullable, [Enabled])
VALUES (1, 1, N'b', N'nvarchar(30)', 1, 1)
    , (2, 1, N'c', N'int', 0, 1)
GO
```

This is the "interesting" dynamic T-SQL code.  It cross joins to `sys.databases` so that a `CREATE TABLE` statement is generated for every database on the instance.  I'm using `WHERE database_id > 5` because I don't have an instance with more than 337 databases - so you'll need to modify that to suit your needs.

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N';CREATE TABLE ' 
    + QUOTENAME(t.TableName) 
    + N'( ' + STUFF((SELECT N', ' 
        + c.ColumnName 
        + N' ' + c.ColumnType 
        + N' ' 
        + CASE WHEN c.Nullable = 1 THEN N'NULL' 
            ELSE N'NOT NULL' 
          END 
    FROM [Table].Columns c 
    WHERE t.TableID = c.TableID 
        AND c.[Enabled] = 1 FOR XML PATH (N'')), 1, 2, N'') + N');'
FROM [Table].Tables t
    CROSS JOIN sys.databases d
WHERE t.[Enabled] = 1
    AND d.database_id > 5;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @cmd;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

The code will "print" a `CREATE TABLE` statement for each database, which you could simply copy-and-paste into a new query window to actually execute.  You could replace the `PRINT @cmd;` with `EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;` to automatically run each `CREATE TABLE` statement, however I wouldn't suggest doing that until you're certain this works the way you expect.

Notice, the code above includes the `Nullable` column - that wasn't in your example code.  It's important to declare the nullability for every column when creating a table.

Also, please don't use reserved words for table names; i.e. don't call a table "Table".  It's frustratingly hard to type and hard to read later.